# What's the correct way to say "I will have been..." in German?

Tags: grammar, translation, subjunctive

Let's say I want to say

> "I will have been a cat."

Is it

> "Ich werde eine Katze gewesen haben.' or
>
> "Ich werde eine Katze haben gewesen."?

I think it's the first one, but I want to check.

Also, while I'm here, if I want to say

> "I would be a cat.", is it
>
> "ich wuerde eine Katze sein" or
> "ich waere eine Katze."?

I'm trying to wrap my head around all the waeren, wuerden stuff, and I need simple examples to understand.

Comment: Some issues: 1) It is better to ask two questions than about two issues in one question. 2) Do you really want to use the [future perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future-in-the-past#Future_perfect) for your first example sentence? 3) Can you give some context for the sentence in your second question?

Comment: Possible Context: "Bis ich ins Nirvana eintrete, werde ich eine Katze gewesen sein."

Answer (score 5):

**First question = Futur 2**

In German Futur 2 is built in the exact same way as Future Perfect in English with the exception, that in German `haben` and `sein` are the auxiliary verbs in contrast to `have` being the only one in English. This exception is important here, as the full verb `sein` is conjugated using `sein` as the auxiliary verb.

Therefore it's

> Ich werde eine Katze gewesen *sein*. (Correct)

instead of

> Ich werde eine Katze gewesen *haben*. (Wrong)

**Second question = Konjunktiv**

The Konjunktiv mood can be built using a simple form or a composed form.

Simple Form:

> Ich *wäre* eine Katze.

Composed Form:

> Ich *würde* eine Katze *sein*.

Both forms are interchangeable. For most verbs, the composed form is used most often. For `sein` both forms probably have the same likelihood.

Comment: For the Konjunktiv(I, as in roman 1): German teachers will tell you that the first form is more correct than the composite form, because the composite form can be confused with the Konjunktiv II (as in roman 2) for some verbs.

Answer (score 2):

The first question seems to point for the tense called "future perfect", or "Futur II" in German. It is used very seldomly to express actions or processes that are known to be terminated at a future point.

The example with the cat would be "Ich werde eine Katze gewesen sein", although that doesn't make sense as a sentence. Other examples:

> "Im Jahr 2133 wird man alle Lebewesen geklont haben."

-> In 2133, all species will have been cloned.

> "In 3484 Jahren werden alle Fisch-Arten ausgestorben sein."

-> Within 3484 years, all fish will have become extinct.

The syntax of "Futur II" is also used to express vague assumptions:

> "Er wird die Tür `schon` geschlossen haben."

-> He surely locked the door.

> "`Aber` das Auto wird `doch wohl` nicht gestohlen worden sein`, oder`?"

-> But the car won't have been stolen, right?

The `highlighted` parts are used in these examples to further strengthen the opinion/emotion of the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Das erste: "Ich werde eine Katze gewesen **sein**".

Das zweite braucht mehr Kontext. "Ich would like to be a cat" => "ich würde gerne eine Katze sein", wobei "ich wäre gerne eine Katze" auch geht; aber "I would be a cat if i liked to eat mice" => "Ich wäre eine Katze wenn ....", hier gibt es keine passende Form mit "würde".

Comment: Der Konjunktiv kann in beiden Fällen einteilig oder zusammengesetzt sein.

Comment: @Toscho... es mag eine regionale Sache sein, aber ich finde "wäre" im zweiten Beispiel weitaus besser und würde "würde sein" immer korrigieren. Selbst wenn es theoretisch möglich ist, ich finde einen Downvote unagemessen, denn (keine Ahnung ob der von dir ist)

Answer (score -2):

> I **will** have **been** a cat. --> I will be a cat but will cease to be.

-->

> Ich **werde** eine Katze gewesen **sein**.

-

> I **would be** a cat. - If I had the **choice**.

-->

> Wenn ich die **Wahl** hätte, **würde** ich eine Katze **sein**.

But

> If I **was** climbing trees, I **would** be a cat.

-->

> Wenn ich Bäume erklimmen **würde**,(dann) **wäre** ich eine Katze.